# is it possible to get value from application 1.exe and passing those values to application 2.exe using C#...?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

is it possible to get value from application 1.exe and passing those values to application 2.exe using C#...?
like application 1.exe is in running mode while application 2.exe also running. Now suppose I want to pass some data from application 1.exe to application 2.exe without manual data entry. Is it possible to do so in automated mode using C#..?

Comment: Possible, yes. Read about IPC (Inter-Process Commnuncation). That said,  there is way too much involved in that for an SO answer, and it isn't something for a beginner to step into lightly.

Comment: It can be done, but it's complicated. Could you not just write data somewhere from exe1 and read it from that place with exe2?

Comment: It can be done simply using wcf with zero configurations. Below I have made a complete example of doing so using WCF

Comment: Believe Me the IPC method is the easiest. One other method is communication with shared memory but in that case you would need to use Win32API objects for MemoryMappedFiles and kernel sincronization objects like Mutex or Semaphores, As i see this could be too much sophisticated for you, and may be isn't necessary for you actual needings.

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is known as *interprocess communication (IPC)*.
There are plenty of communication approaches, which one you should choose basically depends on factors as decoupling in time, synchronization and space (i.e. their properties).

[Some approaches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication#Approaches)

There exist whole courses about these approaches and their benefits/disadvantages. As pointed out in comments I guess this subject is too broad for SO.

---

A quick word :

- Decoupling in **time** : *Does all communicating processes have to be online at the time of communication?*
- Decoupling in **space** : *Does the communicating processes have to know each other?*
- Decoupling in **synchronization** : *Blocking on communication?*

Different approaches have different properties.

An example :

> Approach : Message Queue
>
> Assumptions : Communicating parties
> enqueue/dequeue messages
>
> Properties : **Decoupled in time** (message queue
> is always there, communicating parties can be online/offline),
>
> **decoupled in space** (communicating parties only know the message
> queue),
>
> decoupled in synchronization? (depends on implementation, e.g.
> blocking `dequeue` on empty queue).

Java offers the Java Message Service (JMS) which really [supports a lot of approaches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service#Elements), I guess there must be C# equivalent.

Comment: [Here is a list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx) talking about IPC for windows, so you don't only have Java refrences. I would call JMS's equivilant in .NET [WCF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms735119(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks for the input! :)

Answer (score 0):

You MAY use MemoryMapping so one application write data with identificator to RAM and other reads it, more info available here: [Memory-Mapped Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372(v=vs.110).aspx)

It's one of easiest ways.

Comment: "Have to", not really. Memory maping is a option but it is not the only IPC out there.

Comment: But it's quite straightforward and easy to implement

Answer (score 0):

Memory maps are one way.  Named and unnamed pipes are another.  You could even, if you wanted a more "quick and dirty" way, write to file with one and read it with the other.  There are a few ways.  But I would prefer named pipes out of all of these options.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to achieve it using IPC's mechanism. But you haven't state if the two applications will be running in same machine or not?

Below are the list that could be used to achieve your goal.

- [WCF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms735119%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- [Socket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [DDE](http://ndde.codeplex.com/)
- [Others](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)